# Cloning and building an earlier Mercurial version of code in Bitbucket repository

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I wish to rebuild an earlier version of my code in the Bitbucket repository under Mercurial. The history is at:

```
https://bitbucket.org/petermr/svg2xml-dev/commits/all
```

I intend to use:

```
hg clone -u REV
```

into a new local repository and rebuild as a separate project. My immediate problem is that I know the commit identifier (`abefe99`) but not the numeric revision (which seems to be required by all the `hg` commands). Using the Bitbucket web pages (or possibly my existing local repo) how can I either (a) find the numeric revision or (b) use the identifer for this clone.

(I am reluctant to use `hg revert` or `hg update` as I will probably get them wrong in the first instance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a command says that it takes a `REV`, it can take either the hash or the numeric revision ID.

The command `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/petermr/svg2xml-dev -u abefe99` worked fine for me and left my working copy at the correct changeset.

Comment: +1 thanks. FWIW I found that locally `hg log` gave me the numeric IDs alongside the hash.